# Script printing variable expansion

Tags: bash, scripting, cron

My script is producing some really bizarre output and I don't know why.

Here's the script:
(userslist.temp is a list of usernames, one for each line of the file)

```
printf 'Output Starting:\n\n'
while read line; do
    cronresult=$(sudo crontab -u $line -l)
    printf "$line : $cronresult"
done < userslist.temp
```

The output it produces :

```
Output Starting:

no crontab for thornegarvin
thornegarvin : 
no crontab for testuserone
testuserone : 
no crontab for testusertwo
testusertwo : 
no crontab for testuserthree
testuserthree :
```

My users DO NOT have crontabs configured, but I don't know why the script isn't printing the variables on separate lines.

Comment: What happens if you discard stderr by `2>/dev/null`?

Comment: Whats your question exactly? With no crontabs configured, I don't understand what you would expect to see?

Comment: `$(..)` captures stdout, while error messages like this are written to stderr straight to screen. You can use `cronresult=$(sudo crontab -u "$line" -l 2>&1)` if you want to store errors in the variables as well

Answer (score 0):

So the comments were enough to fix my issue:
The output I was capturing was the standard error output, NOT the standard output as I had thought. I redirected the stderr to /dev/null and set up an if to handle blank stdoutput. Thanks!